# String manipulation in shell in a single line

Tags: string, bash, shell

I am using the below script

```
list=kmakalas@gmail.com;kmakalas@gmail.com;kmakalas@gmail.com;
```

for the above I wanted extract to

```
r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas
```

for that I used the below shell manipulations

```
rev_list="r=${list//@gmail.com;/r=}
```

the above gave me

```
r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas,r=
```

to get `r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas,r=kmakalas`

I used `rev2="${rev_list%,r=}"`

Is there any possibility to do in a single line command

Comment: `list=kmakalas@gmail.com;kmakalas@gmail.com;kmakalas@gmail.com;` will assign the string `kmakalas@gmail.com` to list and then attempt to run `kmakalas@gmail.com` as a command twice.  What is your actual script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -F '[=;]' '{ for(i=2;i<NF;i++) { split($i,map,"@");printf i==(NF-1)?"r="map[1]:"r="map[1]"," } printf "\n" }' <<< "$list"
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F '[=;]' '{                                                     # Set the field delimiter to "=" or ";"
                  for(i=2;i<NF;i++) { 
                      split($i,map,"@");                             # Loop through each field and split the field/address into an array map using "@" as the delimiter
                      printf i==(NF-1)?"r="map[1]:"r="map[1]","      # Print "r=" along with the "@" prefix
                  } 
                  printf "\n" 
                }' <<< "$list"
```